# SQLDataAdapter not doing Bulk Update

Tags: sqldataadapter

I currently have a DataTable that I need to use to do large updates of data on the SQL Server.   When I run the below code and it gets to the update part I can see using the sql profiler that it's making update calls one at at time instead of in bulk.  Am I missing something?

```
    Using myConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)


        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()

        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("updCatMasterFromParcel @ID, @HOMkt, @HOExemp, @PtrMkt", myConnection)


        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "ID")

        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@HOMkt", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "HOMkt")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@HOMkt").Precision = 18
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@HOMkt").Scale = 8

        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@HOExemp", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "HOExemp")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@HOExemp").Precision = 18
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@HOExemp").Scale = 8

        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@PtrMkt", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "PtrMkt")
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@PtrMkt").Precision = 18
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters("@PtrMkt").Scale = 8

        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 120000

        adapter.DeleteCommand = Nothing
        adapter.InsertCommand = Nothing


        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 0
        adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None


        adapter.Update(dt)



    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SQL Profile gives the impression that it's only doing the update one row at a time when in fact it sent all of the updates in one batch but show up as one operation at a time in the profiler.

Found the answer in this article.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccess/archive/2005/05/19/420065.aspx